# Oracle Database Security

Tags: oracle

I'm currently using RHEL 5 and Oracle 11g.

I use DBCA to create Oracle database with all default options available.
The problem is that when I create a new user on that database, this user can connect to the database with sysdba privilege although it is not granted any privileges.

create user backup_admin identified by password default tablespace users;

sqlplus backup_admin as sysdba

What to do to restrict the user from connecting as sysdba?

Comment: Are you logged in to the operating system as the Oracle user (or a member of the DBA group)?

Comment: Yes, I log in to the OS as the Oracle user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The problem is that when I create a new user on that database, this user can connect to the database with sysdba privilege although it is not granted any privileges."

Incorrect. Database users cannot connect as SYSDBA. Connecting as SYSDBA means connecting to the SYS user/schema.

OS users can connect as sysdba if, as Justin mentions, they are in the dba group. This normally includes the oracle user, but maybe others too.

Oracle is a bit misleading that you can try, for example, SQLPLUS user/pass AS SYSDBA
In this case, the user/pass is ignored and it has the same effect as SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA

Comment: It can be helpful to also try the login remotely. ie 'sqlplus /nolog' then 'connect backup_admin/password@tnsdatabasename as sysdba' 
You will probably find that this will not work as the OS level authentication mentioned above won't work for a remote connection.

Comment: Hi Gary, you are right. So how can I restrict the "SQLPLUS user/pass AS SYSDBA"? As u mention, it has the same effect as "SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA".

Regards,
Sarith